# How to walk through the collection of subreports in Crystal Reports 2008?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have the report with lots of sub-reports within.

How can I walk through the collection of sub-reports in main report? I need this to change the data source for each sub report.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited per CodeByMoonlight comment - I haven't tested this yet, but it should be way better than my original.

```
ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
reportDocument.Load(...);
foreach (ReportDocument subreportDocument in reportDocument.Subreports) {   
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: Slightly overkill - there's a SubReports property of the ReportDocument itself, so you don't need to enumerate every single report object and check it's a subreport.

Comment: @moonlight - thanx - that looks much better. My original was code I had been using for years - I wonder if the Subreports property is fairly new, or if I just missed it first time around...

Comment: Much better :) I think it's been there a while, but I've not had call to use it much.